# Open VPN connection time about 15 seconds. Is that normal?

Tags: openvpn

I have a VPN Server.
Server works perfect.

However, it takes about 15 seconds to connect.

from: Attempting to establish TCP connection
to: This computer's apparent public IP address changed from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx before connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx after connection

Is that normal or the connection time should be faster and I am having something wrong in my configuration?

Comment: What vpn client? On what platform?

Comment: Is it slow on the client or server.  Did you make your certs/keys overly large?  What hardware, what algorithms, etc.  Do you have an scripts being ran as part of the startup.  There are large number of factors, that can impact things.  15 seconds, may be perfectly reasonable for your setup.

Comment: Check your logs.